# s3object query returns no result for empty field where clause

Tags: sql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-object-tagging

I'm trying run a query with blank field where clause but it returns no result but with any values same query works fine

Query working fine :

```
SELECT s3o.Id,s3o.Name,s3o.City FROM s3object s3o WHERE s3o.City = 'Toronto'
```

But when I try to get result for blank then it returns nothing

```
SELECT s3o.Id,s3o.Name,s3o.City FROM s3object s3o WHERE s3o.City = ''
```

I didn't find any documentation in case if there's any other way to get result for blank fields, I tried with `IS NULL` as well but not working as expected

Is anyone know if there's any other way to achieve it

Comment: *Is* there an s3o with a City value of `''`?

Comment: `where length(s3o.City) = 0`, or similar?

Comment: yes when I search without any condition it returns all records with empty fields as well